# Is there an easier way to integrate this hectic integral?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, volume

Using triple integrals and cartesian coordinates, find the volume of the solid bounded by $$z=3x^2+3y^2-7 $$ and $$z=9-x^2-y^2$$

> **My take** 
>   I have equated the two solids and found the intersection. My first question is, what is exactly intersecting? I am having trouble picturing it. *contuniung on* The intersection I found is $$x^2+y^2=4$$ and hence the parameters are $$ -2\le x \le 2$$ $$-\sqrt{4-x^2}\le y \le \sqrt{4-x^2}$$  $$3x^2+3y^2-7 \le z \le 9-x^2-y^2 \left( 1 - \frac{y}{b} -\frac{x}{a} \right)  $$ and now I am left with this hectic integral $$ \int_{-2}^{2} \int_{-\sqrt{4-x^2}}^{\sqrt{4-x^2}} \int_{x^2+3y^2-7}^{9-x^2-y^2} 1 dzdydx$$ Is there any easier way to solve this integral? Maybe by changing the parameters but I am not sure how?

Comment: looks like a job for polar coordinates in $x,y$. Once you finish the $z$-integral the bounds in $x,y$ become constant in polar coordinates. I'd try that.

Comment: For your question about what exactly is intersecting, these are two [paraboloids](http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427eu2qn68jlqb).

Comment: @JamesS.Cook Thankyou for your response James, I was taking the time to work it out before I responded and it worked, Thankyou again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use cylindrical coordinates.

$$x=r\cos\theta$$
$$y=r\sin\theta$$
$$z=z$$

$$z=3x^2+3y^2-7\implies z=3r^2-7$$
$$z=9-x^2-y^2\implies z=9-r^2$$

The intersection is now $r=2$.

The volume integral is therefore as follows:

$$V=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{2}\int_{3r^2-7}^{9-r^2}rdz\space{dr}\space{d\theta}$$

This is a much easier integral to calculate.

Comment: It absolutely is, thankyou for your help Zetta